# Rewriting/refreshing multi-line python output

Tags: python, linux, output

I am trying to refresh a multi-line python output but this is a special case. I want to handle the case whee even a single line occupies multiple lines in terminal because may be the line is too big or font size big etc.

I have tried various line moving and line clear ASCII which work fine in general but give weird outputs for the special case I mentioned.

I even thought of using a loop with '\b' to remove everything but it just removes characters from current line and cannot go to the previous line. Is there any other such ASCII to achieve this?

Please help in this as i didn't find solution to this anywhere.

PS: I am using linux OS.

Comment: One very good alternative is to use `ncurses` to do a real screen-managed output.  You can't really deal with terminals with huge fonts unless you limit the line size.  You can use the ANSI escape codes to move the cursor, but that doesn't help if you don't know how many lines to go.

Comment: You might enjoy `rich`, see https://pypi.org/project/rich/

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the issue. I got terminal width using shutil module and then wrapped my lines with python textwrap module. Now ASCII sequences are working fine.